# getUserMedia() shim for PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, stream, camera

I have created a web app with Cordova and I need to show a live camera stream in my background. It seems that the Camera/Videos APIs from Cordova just open the native Camera/Video apps instead of returning live camera data. What I really need is something like `getUserMedia()` which is only available on Opera and Chrome (June 2012).

Is there a shim to use `getUserMedia()` within Cordova or any Plugins which behave similarly?

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using?<br>
Since iOS6, the way you ask to the OS permission for their APIs changed (because they introduced more security).<br>
Look inside **preferences app** if your app is inside **privacy**

Comment: The question wasn't really related to a specific version or setting or platform (it happens on Android, too). It's about a "real" polyfill for an existing API just like Cordovas Geolocation polyfill. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing camera view inside html in android and then snap a picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176334/showing-camera-view-inside-html-in-android-and-then-snap-a-picture)

Answer (score 5):

There's a [plugin](https://github.com/daraosn/Cordova-CanvasCamera) for capturing the camera stream, It uses `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to create a capture session. Each frame is base64 encoded and passed to the Cordova UIWebView. Its experimental and is slower than any native approach.

Comment: @Unreality For android you might be able to use https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html