# Showing camera view inside html in android and then snap a picture

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is there a view of showing the live camera view inside html ( e.g. embedded in a div ) before we snap a picture using JavaScript? I have tried PhoneGap but it totally starts a new camera app and totally moves away from my html web app before returning to it. I need something embedded in my app

Thanks

Comment: Iam Also Facing The Same Problem Did You Get Any Solution For This..If U Get anything Plz Share Your Valueable Comments To Me Also

Comment: @Erma Isabel : No Erma I did not find a solutions to that

Comment: Is There Any Native Android codes To Solve This Problem????

Answer (score 13):

You can install **[mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview](https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview) plugin (for android,ios)** in your Cordova/phonegap application that allows camera interaction from HTML code. A really amazing plugin it is..
You can access Features such as:

**Start a camera preview from HTML code.
Drag the preview box.
Set camera color effect (Android and iOS),Send the preview box to back of the HTML content,Set a custom position for the camera preview box,Set a custom size for the preview box and Maintain HTML interactivity.**

Or you can also use **[donaldp24/CanvasCamera](https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin) Plugin** for your application if it fits to your requirements.Its supported in both android and iOS platforms. I have observed, for iOS its working fine but in android it isn't working.

Now you can install CordovaCameraPreview plugin through Online PhoneGap too. So without using CLI you can directly use it through this by adding

`<gap:plugin name="com.mbppower.camerapreview" version="0.0.8" source="plugins.cordova.io" />`

in your config.xml file and create ApplicationTemplate.apk/.ipa. For more information regarding this you can ask me. Happy to help.

UPDATE:10th Oct 2017
It used to work well during that time but, donaldp24/CanvasCamera is no longer maintained and currently fails build with the latest Cordova version.

Answer (score 4):

I did it for one of my projects. Check out navigator.getUserMedia(). There are a tonne of things you can do with your webcam and browser, including AR games! Here's just a basic example:

**HTML:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
       <form><input type='button' id='snapshot' value="snapshot"/></form> 
       <video autoplay></video>
       <canvas id='canvas' width='100' height='100'></canvas> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="findit.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

**findit.js**

```
    var onFailSoHard = function(e)
    {
            console.log('failed',e);
    }

    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL ;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;

    var video = document.querySelector('video');

    if(navigator.getUserMedia)
    {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true},function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        },onFailSoHard);
    }

    document.getElementById('snapshot').onclick = function() { 
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0); 
    }
```

Live Demo:

[A personal project](http://www.sanjeevmk.in/findit)

More Resources, this is what I used:

[Webcam Access](http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/chapter13.html)

**Update:**

This solution is valid only for front camera if our device has one. It's basically a "webcam" solution. Not sure if it'll work for your case. Just in case, check out the resources.

Comment: Also note that currently `getUserMedia` is poorly supported.

Comment: Chrome has added support for device selection. Checkout this example https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

Comment: According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia) this does not work. The question asks specifically about getting a feed in mobile aps/devices, not just browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `camera.getPicture` from `cordova-plugin-camera` or `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` from `cordova-plugin-media-capture`.

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
        || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
        || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
        || navigator.msGetUserMedia 
        || navigator.device.capture.captureVideo 
        || navigator.camera 
        || camera.getPicture;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct access to the Camera app using javascript. You can either write a custom PhoneGap (Cordova) plugin to do that.

Comment: the question is about accessing the camera with javascript... and not accessing the `camera app` directly...