# Phonegap Camera view inside html(Div) in android/Ios

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, camera

Iam Stuck In my Project For 1 Week Because Of This Camera Issue Now Iam In a Phonegap

Project To Embed a Camera View Inside A Html But I Cant Get That.The Camera Is Showing

Only In a default(native) Mode..i Followed This StackOverFlow Question 
    [[1]: [Showing camera view inside html in android and then snap a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176334/showing-camera-view-inside-html-in-)
       AnyOne Having any Suggestions 
       Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible on android as it doesn't support getusermedia, and a native plugin will show a native view