# GetUserMedia access denied on Cordova Android app, WebRTC and Kurento integration

Tags: android, cordova, getusermedia

I'm trying to make an Android app using Cordova, WebRTC and Kurento. When I try to make a video call using the app I can receive the video and audio from the remote peer, but I'm unable to send my local video and audio to my remote peer. When the call is started I get a Permission Denied on the App.

Follows the code of the function that calls the getUserMedia.

```
getUserMedia = function(constraints, onSuccess, onError) {
alert('getusermedia.adapter');
if (constraints.audio) {
  constraints.audio = constraintsToChrome(constraints.audio);
}
if (constraints.video) {
  constraints.video = constraintsToChrome(constraints.video);
}
webrtcUtils.log('chrome: ' + JSON.stringify(constraints));
return navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(constraints, onSuccess, onError);
};
navigator.getUserMedia = getUserMedia;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `camera.getPicture` from `cordova-plugin-camera` or `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` from `cordova-plugin-media-capture`.

Taken from this [answer to "Showing camera view inside html in android and then snap a picture"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071491/3785349)